# How to programmatically access layer tag colour in Photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I have seen a lot of questions and answers about how to access or change the colour of a fill on a layer through javascript, but that's not what I need. In a Photoshop document you can tag layers with colours in the Layers window.

[image: Demonstration of layer colour tags]

However, in the [reference document](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/JavaScriptReferenceGuide.pdf) I can't find where it offers access to this property. Is there some way I can get access, and use the colours to delineate which layers should and shouldn't be affected by a script I write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed the exact same thing for the same purpose.

Here is the solution, two little helper functions to read or write the color label 
of the active layer: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2238996

> This is using the layer ID.
>
> `$.writeln(getLayerColourByID(4));
>   function getLayerColourByID( ID ) {
>   var ref = new ActionReference();
>   ref.putProperty( charIDToTypeID("Prpr") ,stringIDToTypeID('color'));
>   ref.putIdentifier(charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), ID );
>   return typeIDToStringID(executeActionGet(ref).getEnumerationValue(stringIDToTypeID('color')));
>   };`

thanks @Jeffrey: https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/-ps-scripting-get-color-label-tag-of-a-layer-with-extendscript

Comment: This is great, thanks! I've had trouble getting this to work as I'm also attempting to translate it into Python code but it looks like it'd work fine in actual Javascript.